# iframes switching in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to switch iframes in html which contains video references. Kindly help me with this. Actually i want to check the value i pass through textarea and then according to that value i want to switch frames.

**HTML**

```
 <iframe id="i1"  name="iframeswitch" src="nice-to-meet-you.html"  style="float: left;
position:relative;
height:350px;
width:500px;
margin-left:-25px;"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<iframe id="i3"  name="iframeswitch" src="your-name.html"  style="float: left;
position:relative;
height:350px;
width:500px;
margin-left:-25px;"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
<iframe id="i2" name="iframeswitch" src="deaf-you.html"  style="float: left;
position:relative;
height:350px;
width:500px;
margin-left:-25px;"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
<iframe id="i4" name="iframeswitch" src="you-work-where.html"  style="float: left;
position:relative;
height:350px;
width:500px;
margin-left:-25px;"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0">
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

i made these iframes `display:none;` in my css. and i want them to be displayed in a div named virtual.
    **javascript**

```
  <script>
   function myFunction() {
       var text=document.getElementById('me').value;
       if(text="nice to meet you")
       {
           document.getElementById('i1').style.display="block";

       }
        else if(text="are you deaf")
       {
           document.getElementById('i2').style.display="block";

       }
       else if(text="what is your name")
       {
           document.getElementById('i3').style.display="block";

       }
       else if(text="where you work")
       {
           document.getElementById('i4').style.display="block";

       }
        else
       {}
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a great example why not to use inline CSS, imagine one day you find out your `iframe` should be `width:600px;` instead of `500` ...harsh time.

**You don't need 4+ iframes, but only one.**

```
<input  id=me type=text>
<iframe id=myIframe scrolling=no frameborder=0>Get a Browser</iframe>
```

CSS:

```
#myIframe {

    float       : left;
    position    : relative;
    height      : 350px;
    width       : 500px;
    margin-left : -25px;

}
```

Now, having only one iframe you can build an Object with your associations:

```
var text2src = {
  "nice to..." : "nice.html",
  "want some"  : "want.html",
  "good night" : "night.html"
};
```

and on input change you can than modify the iframe src:

```
var me  = document.getElementById("me");
var ifr = document.getElementById("myIframe");
me.oninput = function(){
  var val = this.value.toLowerCase();
  if(text2src.hasOwnProperty(val))  ifr.src = text2src[val];
};
```